# VBA EXCEL Custom Function runs well but when I summon an UserForm the calculated cell values goes to Zero

Tags: excel, vba

I made a custom function in VBA that works without no major issues.

This function multiplies a range of cells and returns the value based on specific criteria.

Everything works right, but when I run other Function or Subroutine, the values goes to ZERO.

Anyone can help?

```
Option Explicit
Function multiselic(a As Integer, b As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim temp1 As Double

a = a + 1

temp1 = Range("G" & a).Value

a = a + 1

For i = a To b
temp1 = temp1 * Range("G" & i).Value
Next i

multiselic = temp1


End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's an implicit `ActiveSheet`... you haven't specified the worksheet before `Range("G" & a)` and `Range("G" & i)`.

Comment: ^^^^ Add the sheet reference like: `Application.Caller.Parent.` before each `Range`

Comment: Also, you will want to make it Volatile as the criteria do not refer to a range themselves, there is no trigger to recalc if the values change.  Add `Application Volatile` as the first line in the function.

Answer (score 1):

User defined function are not supposed to read from ranges, but must have all information needed as arguments to the function. You have not included how the function is called (cell definition) so I cannot demonstrate how to change the function to make it not use the `Range()` function.

Additionally, a naked `Range()` function uses the `ActiveSheet` to reference values and therefore this function would only work if the source sheet is active. Try using the `Worksheet.Range()` type of reference, such as `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7").Value` to pull a specific value from a cell in a specific worksheet.

Your code can be simplified when calculating the product of cells. No need to peel the first value out first. Just start from 1. Below is an example of a general approach if take the product of `n` values under a range.

```
Public Function ProductOfValues(ByVal r_start as Range, ByVal n as Long) as Double
    Application.Volatile ' Per comments
    Dim i As Long
    Dim temp1 As Double
    If n=0 Then
        ProductOfValues = 1#
        Exit Function
    End If
    temp1 = 1#
    For i = 1 To n
        temp1 = temp1 * r_start.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i
    ProductOfValues = temp1
End Function
```

The function is to be used as `=ProductOfValues(Sheet1!G2, 10)` for example.

PS. Replace all `Integer` types with `Long` as the former is a 16-bit integer and the latter a 32-bit one (which is what you intended here). A 16-bit integer will overflow above 16383 which is easy to get with multiplication.

Comment: You are going to have the same issue here as the OP, the range will refer to the active sheet and once that focus is not on the correct sheet the function will return the wrong values.

Comment: I know, but I cannot correct unless the _op_ shows how the function is used. Nevertheless I edited the answer with a more robust approach, referencing the cells under a specific range, instead of doing string math like `Range("G" & i)`.

Comment: you do not need to know, you only need to know the caller.parent: `Application.Caller.Parent.Cells(i, 1).Value`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have never used `.Caller` before. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ScottCraner - see my edit now. IMHO the intent is clear now and the code itself does not depend on referencing cells, other that the range given as an argument.

Comment: You still need to make volatile or it will not update when the values in Column G change.

Comment: @ScottCraner - how do you mark a function as `Volatile`?

Comment: Add `Application.Volatile` as the first line  in the function.

Comment: `ByRef` is not needed here. `ByVal` is sufficient for the first argument.

Comment: You can `ByVal` a `Range` object? Great.